# GStreamer c++ - seeking before starting any playback

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I added an `start-offset` option to my C++ application using the GStreamer library. It basically tells the application to start mid-video instead of playing from the beginning.

The pipeline is created like this: `filesrc location="file_path" ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! mppvideodec ! waylandsink`. This is what gives me best results on my hardware, and I'm running under Weston (wayland)

I do the seeking with a simple `gst_element_seek` on the pipeline. First I tried waiting until the pipeline changes state to `PLAYING` or `PAUSED` in the bus, and then seeking once.  This worked, but on some larger videos it produced an effect that after launching the app, the first video frame is displayed for a glimpse of a second and then the video actually jumps to the desired position. I don't want that, I'd like to jump right to where I want without displaying anything else earlier.

So I changed my seeking method to happen before I even set the pipeline to `PLAYING` state like this:

```cpp
// seek if needed
  if(startTime > 0) {
      // First set pipeline to PAUSED and wait for async state change
      gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
      gst_element_get_state(m_pipeline, nullptr, nullptr, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);
      if (!gst_element_seek (m_pipeline, 1.0, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, startTime, GST_SEEK_TYPE_NONE, -1)) {
        g_print ("Seek failed!\n");
      }
      gst_element_get_state(m_pipeline, nullptr, nullptr, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE); // wait for seek to finish and then set to PLAYING
  }
  m_ret = gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (m_ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref(m_pipeline);
    exit(0);
  }
```

And while this also works, it unfortunately produces the exact same effect as before...the first frame is still being displayed even though the seek happens before the pipeline is started.

How can I ensure that nothing is displayed until the seek is actually done?

**Update**
I couldn't get any method of seeking to work like I wanted, but I achieved the effect by setting the `show-preroll-frame` on the GstVideoSink before constructing the pipeline, like that:

```cpp
m_sink = gst_element_factory_make("waylandsink", "sink");
g_object_set(m_sink, "show-preroll-frame", FALSE, NULL); // prevent preroll frame when seeking
```

And it works! I'll use it for now if there's no better way. The seek is still done in `PAUSED` state, but video is displayed directly from the seeking point.

Comment: It appears that seeking with the method above (before playback) makes the first frame appear even longer than seeking after state change...

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation of the [gst_element_seek_simple](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstelement.html?gi-language=c#gst_element_seek_simple)  method says:

> Some elements allow for seeking in the READY state...

This is true if the pipeline is completely prerolled before the seek.
Then you can get the result you expect, showing only the frames you expect.

```
 gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
 //make sure all the pipeline is prerolled (dynamic pads linked and other stuff)
 if (!gst_element_seek (m_pipeline, 1.0, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, startTime, GST_SEEK_TYPE_NONE, -1)) {
    g_print ("Seek failed!\n");
  }
  gst_element_get_state(m_pipeline, nullptr, nullptr, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);
```

Comment: This unfortunately results in a "Seek failed" message, how can I ensure that the pipeline is prerolled? I tried adding additional `gst_element_get_state` under the first `...set_state`, but it didn't help

Comment: Or does that mean that my elements don't support seeking in the `READY` state? I currently try to seek when I receive a state change to `GST_STATE_READY`, `GST_STATE_PAUSED` or `GST_STATE_PLAYING` and I'm getting the first successful seek at the `PAUSED` state

Comment: I found an `show-preroll-frame` in some old documentation for gstvideosink, is there any way I could use it in my waylandsink in C++? I think it does what I want.

Comment: Yes! It did the work. I added this line `g_object_set(m_sink, "show-preroll-frame", FALSE, NULL); // prevent preroll frame when seeking
` before constructing the pipeline and it works, nothing is displayed until the seek is done. I'll wait if someone has any better way, if not then I'll add it as an answer

Comment: In my case, I am using a decodebin element so I need all the pads created on the fly linked before seeking. I control it with the pad_added_handler signal. Once all are linked, seek can be performed in the ready state